# How to simulate a Unicode Char "key press" in Mac Os X using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, unicode, keypress, simulate

I want to simulate a unicode character in Mac OS X to send to the Foreground application.
I mean I have a unicode char(can contain Arabic, Chinese, etc.) like 'a' and I want to input it. Please note that I am not trying to use Virtual Keys or Key Codes. Only a character.

Sincerely yours,
Peyman Mortazavi

Comment: possible re-post of [NSEvent.KeyDown is only working on the Search Box (in Mac OS X)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169605/nsevent-keydown-is-only-working-on-the-search-box-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a very good approach but there is still a problem. look at the code then I write what is the current problem.

```
    CGEventRef downEvt = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( NULL, 0, true );
CGEventRef upEvt = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent( NULL, 0, false );
UniChar oneChar = 'h';
CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString( downEvt, 1, &oneChar );
CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString( upEvt, 1, &oneChar );
CGEventPost( kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, downEvt );
CGEventPost( kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, upEvt );
```

The problem is that this event is limited to some sessions like the search box and this is because **kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap** if we change it to **kCGSessionEventTap** then it will only work on Search Box. Not can you help me to combine them to make it apply this event to every sessions.

Regards,
Peyman Mortazavi